# incrementally search excel with pandas to match string

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I'm iterating through excel files and logging rows that contain a string, like so:

```
def find_string_row(toFind, dframe):
    index = 0
    while toFind not in dframe.iloc[index].values:
        print(dframe.iloc[index].values)
        index = index+1
    return index
```

I have some new files that are quite messy, and contain strings with whitespace inside and outside the text. So while the above works for exact matches, it fails for loose matches. How can I rewrite this to find strings in this manner:

```
toFind.replace(" ", "").lower()
```

so if I input a string like "Address 1 23  " and the excel contains "  add ress 12    3" they will match?

Comment: when you are replacing ```" "``` with ```""``` and adding ```lower()``` only ```address123``` will match.

Comment: yep, i tried putting the same string functions on the other side (dframe.iloc[index].values), but i think it's a pandas object, not a string so it errors out. how would I make it symmetric?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def find_string_row(toFind, df):
index = 0
stripped_dfrow= [x.replace(" ", "").lower() for x in df.iloc[index].values]
stripped_tofind = toFind.replace(" ", "").lower() 
while toFind not in stripped_dfrow:
    print(dframe.iloc[index].values)
    index = index+1
return index
```

Your locating all of the values within a row, which should return you a list-like object. So to use the string replace method you'll have to iterate over the list. I used the comprehension above which will remove all of the spaces of each item in the value list.

Comment: thanks, the list comprehension on the pandas object did the trick!